# Internet Explorer: make text fill space

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I know this is pretty specific but i can't seem to find an answer. I know that IE has problems interpreting the sizes of boxes in the layout  but i'm not sure if this has anything to do with my problem.

Basically the text on this page wont fill the available space even though its parent element would allow the text to be all on one line.

[image]

This CSS controls the parent element and links respectively

```
#threeCol { 
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 18px; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; }

#threeCol .col {  
    background: #edf1f7; 
    color: white; 
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 1px; 
    width: 316px; 
    height: 320px; 
}


#threeCol .col.last { 
    margin-right: 0px;
}


#threeCol .col .hl { 
    background: #0F2B6B;
    color: white; 
    display: block; 
    font-size: 1.5em; 
    padding: 20px; 
    text-align: justify;
}


#threeCol .col .cl { 
    background: #e6ebf2;  
    color: #0F2B6B; 
    font-size: 1.1em; 
    line-height: 1.2em; 
    padding: 20px; 
}

#threeCol .col .cl a 
{ 
    background: rgba(15, 43, 107, 0.1); 
    clear: both; 
    color: #0F2B6B; 
    float: left; 
    font-size: 0.85em; 
    margin-bottom: 3px; 
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 15px; 
} 


#threeCol .col .cl a:hover { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    background: rgba(15, 43, 107, 0.8); 
    color: white; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col last">
                <div class="hl">Schools &amp; teachers</div>
                <div class="cl">
                    Educational downloads
                    <br>
                    <a href="materials/schools-resource-pack.pdf">» Schools Resource Pack</a>
                    <br>
                    <a href="http://www.liberty-human-rights.org.uk/materials/human-rights-act-poster-february-2010.pdf">» Human Rights Act Poster</a>
                    <br>
                    <a href="http://www.liberty-human-rights.org.uk/materials/new-guide-to-campaigning.pdf">» Liberty Guide to Campaigning</a>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Also, what rendering mode? (is it in standards mode or compat mode or quirks mode?)

Comment: Versions 8-10 have this problem and its normal rendering mode i believe, im not sure how to switch it as im not used to IE and im using browserStack. HTML source incoming

Comment: re IE's mode: use the IE dev tools to see what mode IE is using. You can get to the dev tools by pressing F12 (yes, even from within browserStack) or by selecting it from the tools menu. In the dev tools window, you'll be able to see the mode info in the top-right. Also, while you're there, the dev tools will allow you to examine the DOM in more detail so you might be able to see what's going wrong by checking a few things in there.

Comment: Yeah i've used the dev tools to check it out, can't make much sense of it though, the elements just look like they would if id put line breaks in or something. They just wont use the available space.

Compatability mode in IE 10 also produces the same error.

Comment: Can you just use white-space:nowrap;?

Comment: That actually sorted it out haven't heard of that rule before but thats no surprise given my level of expertise with CSS. Would you like to put it a an answer and ill mark it correct?

Comment: white-space:nowrap; could break through the box if the text was longer. I think white-space: pre-wrap is needed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which you posted doesn't show the problem which you mentioned in your question

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/zDbqq/)**

Actually, this is expected, because by default - text wraps.

However if you want to use brute force then you can add `white-space: pre-wrap` to your

`#threeCol .col .cl a` class.